# difference of two columns in spark dataframe using java

Tags: java, apache-spark

I tried the options mentioned in the following post but it didn't work in java - [finding the difference of two columns in spark dataframes and appending to a new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43917836/finding-the-difference-of-two-columns-in-spark-dataframes-and-appending-to-a-new?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

[subtract two columns with null in spark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46334705/subtract-two-columns-with-null-in-spark-dataframe?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Please let me know how can I find difference between two column of a dataset using Spark in Java.

Comment: can you post your code and explain what does not work as you expect?

Comment: I was able to resolve it in a regular sql way instead of using when() function. posted by answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it next way. Lets assume, you want additional column with difference:

```
Dataset<Row> ds = // your dataset
ds.withColumn("diff_col", new Column("col1").$minus(new Column("col2"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by using sql way of subtracting the two column values.

```
sqlContext.sql("Select col1, sum(col2)-sum(col3) as resCol from temp group by col1")
```